# Blazor JS routing problem, static _blazor js not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I have a asp.net 6 application I am trying to add a server side blazor component to. I have my program setup, I am calling my component but when I navigate to the page it cant find the static blazor file because its putting in the routing. How do I resolve this?

Also I can get static and ServerPrerendered render modes to work correctly just not Server as it requires the JS.

```
    builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
    builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
    builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();


    var app = builder.Build();

    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.MapRazorPages();
    app.MapBlazorHub();
    app.Run();
```

_Layout.cshtml

```
<script src="~/_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
@await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
```

Search Component Call:

```
<component type=typeof(ItemSearch) param-Search=Model.Search render-mode=Server />
```

On my index page:

```
Information: Normalizing '_blazor' to 'https://localhost:7216/_blazor'.
```

Once I search:

```
https://localhost:7216/Search/_blazor/initializers 404
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution is add base to the head. of _layout.cshtml

```
<head>
    <base href="~/"/> 
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem (already had the base tag) by deleting my project's `obj` folder and restarting Visual Studio.

Comment: This is not the cause